# Using Spring Eureka Discovery Client with SSL

Tags: ssl, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a problem using a spring eureka discovery client (Service A) in combination with an non spring eureka client (Service B). **When i try to get Service B from Service A i get an empty list.**

Both clients register themself successfully to eureka server. I have configured ssl and therefore disabled the nonsecure port everywhere.

When I show up the application infos in eureka server (/eureka/apps) i noticed that the spring eureka client has configured the vipAddress. My non spring eureka client only set the secureVipAddress.

After a deeper look in the code i found out following:

1. The Spring Eureka Discovery Client add the vipAddress everytime ([org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/InstanceInfoFactory.java) - 58)
2. The non Spring eureka client only add the vipAddress if the non secure port is enabled ([com.netflix.appinfo.PropertiesInstanceConfig](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/v1.8.6/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/appinfo/PropertiesInstanceConfig.java) - 167)
3. The Spring Eureka Discovery Client only searches for non secure vipAddresses ([org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClient](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/v1.4.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaDiscoveryClient.java) - 96)

Why does spring only searches for non secure vipAddresses? Is there a way to use these services together with ssl?